# VBA Function to provide a compliance score

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of rules that need to be complied with and would like to know the most optimal way to define a set of rules. Essentially, there are a set of if -> then statements, however I am interested if there are more elegant ways of coding (case statements or some sort of ruleset)

the rules are as follows:

- 5 Points - developer experience = y, impl=y  and support =y  and  > 5
  references
- 4 Points - developer experience = y, impl=y  and  (3 >= 4)
  references
- 0 Point - developer experience = n, impl=n

This is my function:

```
Public Function EvSystem(dev As Integer, impl As Integer, supp As Integer, refs As Integer) As Integer
Dim score As Integer
score = 0
If dev <= 0 Then
    score = 0
    Else
    If (dev >= 1) And (impl >= 1) And ((refs >= 3) And (refs <= 4)) Then
    score = 4
    End If
    If (dev > 1) And (impl >= 1) And (supp >= 1) And (refs >= 5) Then
    score = 5
    End If
 End If
EvSystem = score

End Function
```

Comment: I think this question belongs on [Stack Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move it by clicking *flag* >> *should be closed...* >> *off-topic because...* >> *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*.

Comment: happy to do so.. however,I dont get the Stack Code Review Option?

Comment: Sorry the [process is a little different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204124/can-we-move-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review) to my instructions.

Comment: This question should be in the code review stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function EvSystem(dev As Integer, impl As Integer, supp As Integer, refs As Integer) As Integer
Dim score As Integer

score = -4 * ((dev >= 1) And (impl >= 1) And (refs >= 3)) - ((supp >= 1) And (refs >= 5))
EvSystem = score

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly, you could possibly simplify your code to the following (untested code):

```
Public Function EvSystem(dev As Integer, impl As Integer, supp As Integer, refs As Integer) As Integer
Dim score As Integer
  score = 0
  If (dev > 0) And (impl > 0) Then
    If (refs >= 3) And (refs <= 4) Then
      score = 4
    End If
    If (supp >= 1) And (refs >= 5) Then
      score = 5
    End If
  End If
  EvSystem = score
End Function
```